# I can't change my pom.xml in my CodeNameOne Project

Tags: firebase, pom.xml, codenameone

AT the moment I'm trying to add the SDK Dependency from Firebase to my CodenameOne Project (pom.xml) but I cannot change that file because it is blocked. How can I add the Dependency to my Project?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and ask on [meta] if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 1):

We don't block adding dependencies but adding a Firebase dependency won't work since this isn't Android. Firebase is a native android dependency, it won't work on iOS etc.

You can add it in the native pom for Android and could probably use cocoapods for iOS support but this would require writing native code and probably not worth the hassle.